# How do the different variants of Loki have different timelines?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

I am confused about how many variants there are in Loki.  Do they all exist in multiple universes? How does a nexus event force them to be pruned?

Answer (score 4):

There are an infinite number of variant Lokis - one for every possible universe within a multiverse.

A nexus event is caused when someone with free will carries out actions which branches the timeline away from the "Sacred Timeline" which is the job of the TVA to maintain. Since they don't want that, when they detect such events they interfere at that point, and prune the variant and the whole branched reality to try and keep things on the track they want.

Comment: So before the events of the Loki TV show was there just one timeline, and all other branches were pruned or were there an infinite number of timelines, and they were all protected by TVA to be exactly the same as the "main" one?